# When and How InnoDB access its metadata or index?

Tags: metadata, innodb, storage-engines

There is few information about the read path or write path with respect to the role of metadata or index. I mean I cannot really understand how InnoDB manage its metadata, and when to access it in order to execute a query.

Can you please name some keyword or provide docs which could make this clear?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 5.6, you can extract metadata about schema objects managed by InnoDB using InnoDB INFORMATION_SCHEMA system tables.

Read more on oracles website: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/innodb-information-schema-system-tables.html

Comment: Thank you for your time! But I still don't really understand how metadata or index is accessed within a query flow, can you take up some keywords so that I can make a thoroughly learning?